# How can I return (fetch) the subject using Dovecot's `doveadm fetch`?

Tags: email, dovecot

Dovecot allows me to search on `SUBJECT` returning the `body`

```
doveadm fetch -u myUser body SUBJECT mySubject
body:
My Body of message
```

This shows me it knows what a `SUBJECT` is, but when I try to return `subject`'s

```
doveadm fetch -u myUser subject ALL
```

I get,

> Available fetch fields: `hdr.<name> body.<section> binary.<section> user mailbox mailbox-guid seq uid guid flags modseq hdr body body.snippet text text.utf8 size.physical size.virtual date.received date.sent date.saved date.received.unixtime date.sent.unixtime date.saved.unixtime imap.envelope imap.body imap.bodystructure pop3.uidl pop3.order refcount storageid`
>
> Fatal: Unknown fetch field: subject

How do I return the subjects of all messages for the user?

Answer (score 2):

The subject is part of the header (`hdr`), so what you want is

```
doveadm fetch -u myUser hdr.subject ALL
```